# In SSMS (Sql Server management Studio) how do I add a row to when a column is read only?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

How do I add a row to when a column is read only?  I think this issue I am having is because I am using an ID field (column) that is automatically generated and incremented whenever a new row is added in Microsoft SQl Server Management Studio, I cannot manually change an ID field and it appears a different (grayer) color.

Somehow, once, after I entered all the other items in the row and hit "Enter" on my keyboard, I managed to have a row added and the ID field was automatically generated.  The problem is that it did not seem to add it out of sequence.  I do not know why it would be 159 and not 157

http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/sql%20server/stuck_zps00d884e5.png

I deleted the row and tried again.  This time, it gave me an error:

http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/sql%20server/stuck02_zpsf175086e.png

When I try to edit the field by hand, it seems i am not allowed to:

http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/sql%20server/stuck03_zpse022ed98.png

Please advise.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

If this helps, here are the version numbers:

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  --- 10.50.2500.0

Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools ---        10.50.2500.0

Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) --- 6.1.7601.17514

Microsoft MSXML             ---     3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0

Microsoft Internet Explorer     ---     9.0.8112.16421

Microsoft .NET Framework                2.0.50727.5466
Operating System                        6.1.7601

Comment: Your column is an identity column, so the value gets generated automatically. Why do you care that the value is `159` instead of `157`?, it shouldn't have any real meaning.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking how to `INSERT` data using SSMS, or are you asking why the new ID value was out of sequence? Either way, I suggest that you stop using the GUI to manipulate data and write SQL scripts instead, it will give you much more control and understanding.

Comment: OK, I understand.  I should ignore this the ID field.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a row in the database, the ID column does not reset. Instead, the table marches on with the next ID in the sequence.

You insert a row, get ID#1, insert a row, get ID#2, then delete row #2.
You're expecting the next insert to be #2 but it will be in fact #3.